# Visual Studio tab lines "-"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm a beginner user to Visual Studio and I got these annoying lines to the left of my code

How can I remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable **visible white space** from the *Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space* menu or using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and accurate answer. I have now reached 15 points so I can upvote you